# UISegmentedControl Extensions Using Swift Callbacks Closure

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to create an extension on the `UISegmentedControl`. I need to call the callback closure each time the user selects the segment of the segmented control. Is there any way to call the closure callback when the segmented item is selected?

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    static func create(with items:[String], callback: (Int) -> ()) -> UISegmentedControl {

        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

        return segmentedControl
    }

    func segmentedControlValueChanged(segmentedControl :UISegmentedControl) {

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is my solution. Although I had to change the static create function extension to instance.

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

private var xoAssociationKey :UInt8 = 0

extension UISegmentedControl {

    var callback :(Int) -> ()  {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&xoAssociationKey) as! (Int) -> ()
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &xoAssociationKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    func create(with items:[String]) -> UISegmentedControl {

        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

        return segmentedControl
    }

    func segmentedControlValueChanged() {
        self.callback(self.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

}
```

Comment: using the objective c runtime for associated objects is really cool, but a little hack-y. Have you considered just making a subclass and keeping the closure stored in a property? You'd get the same behavior but it'd be a much simpler implementation and you wouldn't be relying on the objc runtime for the functionality.

Comment: Absolutely! Subclassing is a much simpler option in this case. I hope this limitation is address in Swift 4. :)